# Redshift: SQL Error [XX000]: ERROR: invalid value for "YYYY" in source string

Tags: subquery, amazon-redshift, common-table-expression

I have edited this legacy script a bit trying not to break a working script. It contains multiple CTEs and in the last statement calls the aggregated and calculated variables created within the CTE. The CTEs run fine from a - c, however with the addition of the final statement breaks the code: *SQL Error [XX000]: ERROR: invalid value for "YYYY" in source string*. Would appreciate suggestions or changes.

```
with a as (
    select
    to_date(df.launch_date, 'YYYYMMDD', FALSE) as n_date,
    df.new_name, df.link, df.uid
    from (
        select
        SPLIT_PART(descriptive_field,'_',4) as launch_date,
        descriptive_field as new_name,
        embedded_link as link,
        autocreated_id as uid
        from database.schema.table1
        union
        select
        SPLIT_PART(ndf_descriptive_field,'_',4) as launch_date,
        ndf_descriptive_field as new_name,
        embedded_link as link,
        autocreated_id as uid
        from database.schema.table2
    ) as df 
    where n_date ~ '.*2022.*'
),
b as (
    select link, uid, 
    case
        when link ILIKE '%-type1%' THEN title_name||'-type1' 
        when link.... 
        else new_name
        end as new_name
    from a
), 
c as (
    select 
    new_name, 
    case
        when link ilike ....
        when (link ilike .... )
        end as link_grouping,
    count(distinct(uid)) as dist_usr_cnt
    from b
    group by 1,2
)
select 
c.new_name, 
a.n_date,
c.link_grouping,
c.dist_usr_cnt
from c 
join a on c.n_name = a.new_name
where a.n_date >= current_date-7 
and a.n_date <= current_date-3
order by 2,1,3
;
```

Comment: to_date(df.launch_date, 'YYYYMMDD', FALSE) as n_date, 

Check this line, specifically "df.launch_date". 

I would check the values in the database for the column. I'd be willing to bet some of the data was parsed incorrectly and has the values YYYY in the date.